# Fuse symbol on toroidal transformer

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, mains

I was searching today for a new 24V transformer, and I found that some of them have a "fuse" symbol on their label, and I was wondering what this fuse symbol means?

Does the fuse symbol on a transformer (toroidal or not) mean that the fuse is integrated in the transformer's winding?

Or does the "fuse" symbol try to suggest what kind of fuse has to be used with that transformer?

Here you can find an image with the transformer label:

[image: Photo of toroidal transformer showing label, from RS Components]

<sub>(Image source: [RS Components - 2 Output Toroidal Transformer, 120VA, 2 x 25V ac](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/toroidal-transformers/6719006/))</sub>

Comment: There is no room to integrate the fuse. I have worked with such toroids and found that to install even a thermo-disc cutoff I had to epoxy it to the inside of the core, where there is the most amount of heat.

Answer (score 6):

In this case the fuse symbol indicates the fuse rating you should use. 2.40AT means you should use a 2.40A [slow acting fuse](http://www.swe-check.com.au/pages/learn_fuse_speed.php) (type T, T stands for Trage). Trage can be translated from German to sluggish, slow-moving.  You can verify that the 2.40A matches the rated current for each secondary of the device you are considering.
[image: device specs]
The [datasheet](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/157a/0900766b8157a9c2.pdf) mentions no fuse, so it should not be integrated.

Comment: So what is the 'T' in 2.40AT?

Comment: @Transistor it's the speed of the fuse, I will change my answer.

Comment: I found the same info in the RS catalog. See [2.25A Glass Cartridge Fuse, 5 x 20mm, Speed T](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/cartridge-fuses/9113408/). The [datasheet](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/157d/0900766b8157d79f.pdf) is a bit vague although it does give the \$ I^2t \$ ratings.

Comment: 'T' stands for Trage which stands for ...? (I'm making you work for your +1!)

Comment: Yes, you are, haha. Learned more than I expected from it though.